# Show that $4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n +1$ is composite for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

Tags: number-theory

> Show that $4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n +1$ is composite for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: $4$, $6$, $4$, $1$ is almost a row of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Also, $-\frac{1}{2}$ is a root.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg An interesting way to say that $2n + 1$ can be factored out.

Comment: Hint: Factorise $(n+1)^4 - n^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F(n)=4n^3+6n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)(2n^2+2n+1)$$
Hence $f(n)$ is composite for $n=1,2,3,...$

Answer (score 2):

As echoed in the comments, the given question can be solved by noticing that the given expression is actually the binomial expansion of $(n+1)^4$ devoid of the first term. If $n^4$ is added and subtracted, we get $(n+1)^4-n^4$. Factorising, using $a^2-b^2$, we get, $(2n+1)(2n^2+2n+1)$. Both the factors are $>1$. Can you take it from here now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok
We have
f(n)=4$n^3$+6$n^2$+4n+1

We know that -1/2 is a root of this equation by *trail and error method*
So n=-1/2

2n+1 is a factor

Dividing the given equation with 2n+1 we get

*f(n)*=(2n+1)(2$n^2$+2n+1)

So for any n=1,2,3.....

We get f(n) as a composite number with

2n+1 as factor where n€1,2,3....